# Convert JSON input to output

Tags: json, jsonata

How can I convert the following JSON with JSONata.
I need to convert the "value" object, to be an array of key/pair values

Input:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attribute": "line_items",
            "value": [
                {
                    "item_base_total_amount_base": "89.00",
                    "item_order_number": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute": "tax_breakdown",
            "value": [
                {
                    "tax_rate": "0",
                    "tax_base": "635.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "attribute": "line_items",
            "value": [
                {
                    "attribute": "item_base_total_amount_base",
                    "value": "89.00"
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "item_order_number",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute": "tax_breakdown",
            "value": [
                {
                    "attribute": "tax_rate",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute": "tax_base",
                    "value": "635.00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Tried with each function recursively but did not manage to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [transform operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform) to update only the nested "value" attribute with the help of the [$each function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#each):

```
$ ~> |data|{
  "value": $each(value[0], function($value, $attribute){{
    "attribute": $attribute,
    "value": $value
  }})
}|
```

Check it out on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/TJV4zaY